# IOS wrong animation displaying

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewanimation

I've an animation with height increasing/decreasing(to hide and show UIDatePicker). Increasing works like it should, but i've some issue with decreasing. UIDatePicker shrinks and animation starts almost at top, close to the end of the process, and starts to decreasing with a delay. But it still takes the same time as increasing if delay included.

Encreased UIDatePicker

[image: Encreased UIDatePicker]

Starting of decreasing

[image: Starting of decreasing]

My viewWillLayoutSubviews() method

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    frameDatePicker = remindDatePicker.frame
    zeroFrameDatePicker = CGRect(x: (frameDatePicker?.origin.x)!, y: (frameDatePicker?.origin.y)!, width: (frameDatePicker?.width)!, height: 0)
    if reminderSwitch.isOn {
        remindDatePicker.frame = frameDatePicker!
    } else {
        remindDatePicker.frame = zeroFrameDatePicker!
    }
}
```

My showDatePicker() animation method

```
    func showDatePicker() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animateTime, animations: {
            self.remindDatePicker.frame = self.frameDatePicker!
    })  
}
```

My hideDatePicker() animation method

```
func hideDatePicker() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animateTime, animations: {
        self.remindDatePicker.frame = self.zeroFrameDatePicker!
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the real problem here is that a picker (such a date picker) is not intended to have zero height (or any very small height, really). If I were you, I would think of a whole different way of bringing this picker into and out of visible existence.

What Apple does in something like the Calendar app is keep the picker at its normal fixed height but grow and shrink *its superview*, whose `clipsToBounds` is true. Thus, the picker *seems* to grow and shrink, but it isn't really.

Comment: I thought `Calendar` app was using `UITableView` and `deleteRowAtIndex` with animation param.

Comment: @Ryan But how does that work? The _cell_ shrinks, not the date picker.

Comment: date picker must be a subview of cell's content view.

Comment: @Ryan obviously. Please stop going on about this. If have a better answer, give it. I have said what I have said.